# Does MediaCodec support variable frame rates

Tags: android-mediacodec

When encoding a video using MediaCodec, I set the encoder configurations like this:

```kotlin
val format = MediaFormat.createVideoFormat(videoMime, width, height)

format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_COLOR_FORMAT, MediaCodecInfo.CodecCapabilities.COLOR_FormatSurface)
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_BIT_RATE, 4000000)
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_I_FRAME_INTERVAL, iFrameIntervalSeconds)
format.setInteger(MediaFormat.KEY_FRAME_RATE, frameRate)
```

This implies that the `KEY_FRAME_RATE` is a fixed value. But I'm recording a video stream from the web on-the-fly and the frame rate for this stream can vary as the video is being streamed. Does MediaCodec support encoding videos where the frame rate can vary?

The documentation states the following:

> For video encoders this value corresponds to the intended frame rate, although encoders are expected to support variable frame rate based on buffer timestamp. This key is not used in the MediaCodec input/output formats, nor by MediaMuxer.

This begs the question as to what the purpose of the KEY_FRAME_RATE is even used for when it states that it is "intended". It also states that encoders are expected to support variable frame rate. Yet Android only ships with its own encoders, so I suppose that means that they do support variable frame rates. But then it says the key is not used by MediaCodec. Like what is that suppose to mean? It seems like it says it supports it, yet doesn't use it. This is very unclear.